# Onde coloco minhas classes no padrão MVC?

Tags: php, mvc, design-pattern

Estou escrevendo uma aplicação MVC em PHP e a estrutura de diretórios é a seguinte:

```
- root
    ¬ app
        ¬ controllers
        ¬ models
        ¬ views
    ¬ core
        ¬ config
    ¬ public
```

- Na pasta “app” fica as camadas MVC.
- Em “controllers” coloco classes que vão receber dados e acionar
  models e/ou renderizar views.
- Nos “models” coloco basicamente as entidades do banco de dados e suas
  operações. Em “views” coloco as páginas com código html + php para
  exibição de dados.
- No “core” coloco classes e/ou arquivos genéricos (tenho planos de
  usar essa mesma base para desenvolver outras aplicações futuramente,
  uma espécie de microframework).

No entanto surgiu duas classes um pouco diferentes, uma delas trabalha com datas e realiza operações como conversão e cálculo entre datas, a outra cria e gerencia múltiplas threads. Tenho dúvida em qual camada devo colocá-las, já que nenhuma delas fazem acesso a banco de dados ou arquivos e nem emite saídas, apenas retornam valores.

1. Devo criar uma camada adicional? Qual?
2. Devo colocá-la em um das camadas já existentes?

**Obs:** qualquer informação adicional que possa ser útil é sempre bem-vinda!

Comment: Você pode criar um diretório `helper` com códigos genéricos que serve para ajudar em diversas partes da aplicação

Comment: Tá ai o maior erro de artigos e até de algumas respostas aqui do site e de outros sites sobre TI, afirmam para nós coisas sobre MVC que não são verdades e com certeza daqui a pouco vai chegar uma ou mais respostas para ti afirmando coisas como "o correto é X" ou "as boas praticas dizem"... Aliais, muita gente pensa que Model sempre se refere ao banco de dados, muitos até escrevem a estruturas de models como sendo conexões com bancos e tabelas, então aparecem frameworks que seguem certas estruturas PRÓPRIAS e o povo pensa que aquilo é o correto e saem por artigos e respostas promovendo [...]

Comment: [...] "a palavra" e no momento que pergunta de criar uma camada ou não já mostra que lhe "ensinaram" bem errado o que é MVC, vc pode até usar um framework MVC pronto, mas não significará que você esta usando MVC, pois até mesmo nesta estrutura uma pequena diferença de uso pode fazer com que algo simplesmente não seja mais o que foi proposto, vou lhe contar **4 coisas**:

Comment: **PRIMEIRO:** eu passei pelas mesmas duvidas que você e fui também "ensinado errado" - **SEGUNDO:** MVC não é dependente de orientação a objetos - **TERCEIRO:** MVC veio bem antes da WEB e do OOP - **QUARTO:** você pode criar um MVC com três ou menos arquivos PHP puros, sem OOP, sem funções e com no máximo algumas instruções de lógica.

Comment: Desculpe, mas ainda continuo com a dúvida :/

Comment: Se quer separar por responsabilidades, não é o Controller que aciona os models. O Controller, que eu prefiro chamar de resource é responsável por gerar uma resposta http a partir de uma requisição. Toda a lógica por trás disso é implementada de forma independente do protocolo HTTP. Por exemplo, os meus "controllers" costumam ter 5 linhas, as vezes nem isso.

Comment: Se pudessem responder as perguntas do tópico e justificá-las eu seria grato, dessa forma poderia raciocinar em cima da resposta e finalmente aprender. :\

Answer (score -4):

Bom amigo apesar da dúvida ser de certa forma antiga, eu sinto na responsabilidade de responder.

Bom vamos lá, supondo que você está escrevendo uma classe php , que não corresponde exatamente ao model ou controller , vc pode optar por criar uma nova pasta e colocar a nomeclatura que desejar, por padrão existem os helpers, ou uma pasta class mesmo, ali dentro costumamos deixar arquivos que são responsáveis por tarefas bem especificas nos nossos sistemas.

Isso ajuda muito, quando a nomeclatura segue um padrão de psr-4* e assim por diante.

De fato é possivel escrever um MVC, de maneira mais "iniciante". Contudo prezar sempre pelas boas práticas é o melhor caminho.